# Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

How can I set values on to a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model?

In the models.py

```
class BookUser(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()

class Book(models.Model):
    author_id= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    send_to = models.ManyToManyField(BookUser, through='BookUserRelationship')
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    file_size = models.CharField(null=True)

class BookUserRelationship(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(BookUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shared_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,blank=True)
```

Tried to update in serializers.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    send_to = BookUserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta():
        model = Book
        fields = ('book_id', 'author_id','file_size','send_to')

class BookUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = BookUser
    fields = ('email')
```

In the views.py for listing the books by passing the book_id as query params

```
class BookListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.BookSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        book_id = self.request.query_params.get('book_id', None)
        if book_id:
            book = models.Book.objects.filter(book_id=book_id)
             return Response(serializers.BookSerializer(book[0]).data)
```

Comment: This is too broad. You need to show your models, and what you tried.

Comment: I am very new in the Django drf programming, can you please help me with the problem? Edited the question and added the models.

Comment: Thanks but you also need to show how you are trying to set the values.

Comment: Can you please help me with solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything at all. You have already set the relevant data in your for loop, by creating the BookUserRelationship instances. That *is* the many-to-many relationship; you should just remove the `instance.send_to.set(emails)` line.

Comment: Thankyou, But while taking the response I am not getting it. Instead of that error 'str' object has no attribute 'values' is coming.

Comment: Where is that error happening? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with this code. Please edit the question to show the full traceback.

Comment: Can you please have a look into this problem. The send_to field is having the value None

Comment: added BookUserSerializer also, Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't replicate this. Are you sure the book has users?

Comment: If I remove this : _send_to = BookUserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)_, then the response  will have the ids of Bookusers in the send_to field.

Comment: Since I am very new to this drf programming ,can you please help me with suggestions. Tried out all possible solutions.

Comment: Are you sure the definition of BookUserSerializer is correct? You seem to be missing the Meta class.